# Error when installing Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minumn Runtime - 12.0.21005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I get these error messages when trying to install MS Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition on a Win 7 Pro machine from an ISO installation file.

Do you know how t ofix it?

**ERROR:**

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minumn Runtime - 12.0.21005 
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
```

**WARNING:**

```
  The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
```

**WARNING:**

```
  The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved downloading and installing

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_3

Comment: Same environment and same error, but not solved with installing VC++ Redistributables

Comment: Try to download vs_ultimate_download.exe and install it from web download without using the iso. It seems that the iso image does not contain all files for a quick installation. Here the link from MS http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40778

Comment: Well I installed from the ISO and everything worked perfectly. The installation took only 10 minutes on my SSD.

Comment: good to hear it. my iso was from bizspark program, we tried on several machine no ways to make it work. what is the has of your iso?