# Visual Studio 2013 won't install at all

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded visual studio professional 2013 with Update 4 from microsoft official website :

> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/

No matter what i do, it won't install. It gives me some error :

1. Microsoft Visual C++ X64 Minimum Runtime 12.0.21005 
   The Form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
2. Microsoft visual studio 2013 Pre-Clean Tool.
   The Form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
3. Misrosoft Visual Studio Preparation.
   The Form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

I have tried searching everything on web, couldn't find any specific solution.

Some blogs say that it has to be Visual Studio Update 4 and not Visual Studio with update 4, will i have tried both. None of them seems to be working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when installing Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minumn Runtime - 12.0.21005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786654/error-when-installing-visual-studio-2013-ultimate-microsoft-visual-c-2013-x6)

Comment: Try searching for the DLL missing. Install those from the msdn. This problem always gets solved when you install a specific DLL missing. Its your turn to now find that which DLL fits into the requirements. @Prashant

Comment: @BJMyers Thanks for the link you shared. That had fixed the issue.

Comment: @MalikAsif I appreciate your contribution on the question but this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19786748/3901550) fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error C++ X64 Minimum Runtime 12.0.21005
Try install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013

It's on the same page as Visual studio 2013 downloads. 
Scroll down to Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

Second error I found this (maybe) fix on the [Visual studio forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/611f5b18-53cf-476d-8213-72edf05d6343/visual-studio-2013-professional-wont-install-clean-up-tool?forum=vssetup)

Not sure about the third error maybe try see if the above works and then try and tackle the third error.